# Barcode scanner on browser is not showing camera but Enter barcode value (empty value will fire the error handler)

Tags: ionic-framework, browser, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am using following library for barcode scanner

```
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner

$ ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 
$ npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner
```

Run ionic application on browser using  this cmd :

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

code for scan is below:

```
scanCode() {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
      this.scannedData = barcodeData.text;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error', err);
    });
  }
```

There are two issues using the browser :

1. In the case below command, it is showing below error.

   ionic serve

   error on console.log :

   common.js:350 Native: tried calling BarcodeScanner.scan, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

   Error cordova_not_available

cordova.js is already in www/index.html

2. then I decided to run on browser with Cordova plugin

ionic cordova run browser

Scanner button below showing msg

[image]

I need camera not message like this... For android and iOS platform .. It is working well but if I run application for browser it is not showing camera. Any suggestion??

Comment: Plugins only work on devices you have to emulate in order to test it. setup your android studio fire android emulator and run ionic cordova run android -l.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the application is not loading with this command  ionic Cordova run android -l

Comment: you need to have android studio and emulatro for that

Comment: I have an emulator from my latest version of android studio. this issue is only an in-browser platform. I can execute camera on android and ios platform but not in browser platform

Comment: yes exactly barcode scanner and camera are plugins which only work on mobile platform. they made some adjustments in order to work on browser but they are not fully functional just test it on your mobile or emulator if it work then you are good.